# Python Library with options to add books, shows all books, delete and display details of the books

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
library = ['Harry Potter','Lord of the rings','Lupin']

user_input=input('Choose option: ')

# When adding a book , it is not saved in library, it only prints out what was by default. 
  How to save books in Library?

if user_input == 'add_book':
    x = input('add_book: ')
    library.append(x)
elif user_input =='show_books':
    for e in library:
        print((e),end=' ')

# How to specify which book to remove?    

elif user_input =='remove':
    library.pop()
```

> Where to place details for each book? Details should appear when book is selected.

Comment: Perhaps you want to [python class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) with properties like title, author, etc.? Or maybe just a list of [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) representing the books.

Comment: @Mark, Not by class. I have to practice to do it in another way , something like this I've started.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question was how to save data which is added by append, now I see I had to place is in variable so it is saved in memory, and I resolved problem with how to implement logic for showing details about the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code resolves the problems you stated in your comments, the following points explain the changes.

```
library = ['Harry Potter','Lord of the rings','Lupin']

while True:
    user_input = input('\n Choose option: ')

    if user_input == 'add_book':
        to_add = input('add_book: ')
        library.append(to_add)
    elif user_input =='show_books':
        for e in library:
            print((e),end=' ')
    elif user_input =='remove_book':
        to_remove = input("remove_book: ")
        library.remove(to_remove)
    elif user_input == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print("Available options: add_book, show_books, remove_book, quit")
```

1. `While True` lets your entire algorithm start again until `user_input == 'quit'`, when the `break` command tells the program to exit the `While True` loop, ending the program. This was necessary to solve the problem you described of the program not saving changes: the reason was your program ended after your first input, and when you start the program again, it only runs its source code, so it couldn't show any "changes" to variables you made using it previously. Now until you type `quit` it "saves" every change you make.
2. I used `library.remove()` because it accepts the library key value as an argument. `library.pop()` required the index instead. (Now you just need to enter the item (book) name.

( I couldn't implement the last function you described)

> Where to place details for each book? Details should appear when book is selected.

You didn't describe the concept of "selecting" a book and what are the "details" of one.

Hope I've been of some help.

Comment: Details should be like : The author and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Comment: You did help me understand why it was not saving data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to implement logic for **displaying** **details** about **selected** book.

```
elif user_input == 'book_details':
        which_book = input('Which book: ')
        if which_book == 'Harry Potter':
            print('\n''Author: J. K. Rowling')
            print('ISBN: 9780747532743')
            print('Year of release: 1997')
        if which_book == 'Lupin':
            print('\n''Author: Maurice Leblanc')
            print('ISBN: 9780141929828')
            print('Year of release: 1907')
        if which_book == 'Lord of the rings':
            print('\n''Author: J. R. R. Tolkien')
            print('ISBN: 9788845292613')
            print('Year of release: 1954')
```